# Azure Blob Storage Issue with downloading a file

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm working on functionality to allow users to download Azure Blob Storage items.

I am trying to get a list of blobs using:

```
 var list = await container.GetBlobsAsync(BlobTraits.All, BlobStates.All, string.Empty).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Here is the error I have though:

**Error CS1061  'ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Is async available for C# 7.3? Or to use Async calls to obtain all the blobs in the container I need to upgrade to 8.0 C#?

If I change the code to this:

```
            await foreach (BlobItem page in container.GetBlobsAsync(BlobTraits.None, BlobStates.None, string.Empty))
            {
                yield return container.GetBlobClient(page.Name);
            }
```

Then I have this error:

**Error CS8370  Feature 'async streams' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater.**

I know GetBlobsAsync() returns `AsyncPageable<>` and I'm assuming it is only available in C# 8.0?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are the 2 options I can think of :

1. update you're langVersion to 8 which you are saying you do not want to do
2. use an enumerator eg

   ```
   var blobs = blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync()
   List<BlobItem> blobList = new List<BlobItem>();
   IAsyncEnumerator<BlobItem> enumerator = blobs.GetAsyncEnumerator();
   try
   {
       while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync())
       {
           blobList.Add(enumerator.Current);
       }
   }
   finally
   {
       await enumerator.DisposeAsync();
   }
   ```

Comment: What would I need to add to the csproj file? Or that is how I would upgrade to C# 8.0? I do not think we are ready to go to C# 8.0 yet though.

Comment: Thank you for your help and time to look at my issue!

Comment: This saved my ass from having to upgrade the Lang Version to 8 and then have to update a load of nuget packages. Thank you!